# How do I extract contents of SVN repositories without Tortoise installed?

Tags: svn

I have some backups of SVN repositories, the folder contents look like:

```
 -conf
 -dav
 -db
 --revprops
 --revs
 --transactions
 -hooks
 -locks
```

Without installing and setting up SVN to import these into, is there any tool or methodology out there for extracting the source code contents of these repositories?

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 2):

No. You need a SVN client in order to get code out of a SVN repository. Remember that a SVN repository is a binary object. There isn't a file on the file system you can just grab.

You don't have to "set up" SVN though. You just need to install a SVN command line. Why don't you want to